# Can I create a contextual Multi-Armed Bandit Agent in SB3?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I wonder if it is possible to create an agent equivalent to a `contextual Multi-Armed Bandit` using the SB3 library.

It seems to me a much simpler agent, but checking the library documentation they say they don't cover that kind of algorithm, and I wonder if it is possible to create a similar agent (without trajectory interpretation) by tuning one of the existing agents.

My first approach was to use any agent by assigning a value of `gamma=0`, but I think that would not be mathematically correct.

Comment: Have you found an answer yet?

Comment: @paperplan3 Yes. Theoretically you can put gamma=0 on PPO (for example), and it would act as a contextual Multiarmed Bandit: https://www.reddit.com/r/reinforcementlearning/comments/i1hgdr/can_qlearningpolicy_gradient_methods_be_used_for/

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! Im currently reading into contextual and adverserial bandits and the algorithms used. Its always mentioned UCB, Epsilon-Greedy and Exp3 for example. But when I look into SB3 those Algorithms never got mentioned anywhere. I do think its the more general RL algorithms. But how do I apply them to bandit problems. Is there any documentation/literature on this ?

Comment: @paperplan3 From what little I know, I think you are confusing the RL algorithm as such with the exploration method it uses. For example, multi-arm bandits are one type of algorithm, but they can use different exploration methods: UCB, Epsilon-greedy etc.

But you are right, in SB3 I have not seen any allusion to this, but there should not be any problem to use other type of algorithms with the trick that they comment in the post of the link above.

In my case I am testing with PPO using the gamma=0. I still can not confirm that it works, if I have any news I will comment here.

Comment: You got any news on using SB3 algorithms like PPO as contextual bandit algorithms ?

Comment: @paperplan3 Yes, I just setted gamma=0 and It works fine. In fact, if you do the equations of PPO with gamma=0 you can see that the advantage function is easier to learn, for example.